# Add different class name on same navigation depends by page

Tags: php

My navigation is called on all page with code `<?php include 'navigation.php'; ?>`. Navigation I want to use on all pages:

```
<nav class="white-color">
    <!-- nav code -->
</nav>
```

But I need to change `class="white-color"` on specific pages to be `class="black-color"`. Is there a option to add simple PHP code to define:

```
<?php
   if($page == "index") {
       echo '
             <nav class="first-class">
             </nav>
       ';
   } else if($page == "register") {
       echo '
             <nav class="second-class">
             </nav>
       ';
   } else {
       /* DEFAULT CLASS FOR PAGES*/
       echo '
             <nav class="third-class">
             </nav>
       ';
   }
?>
```

Or maybe I can resolve this with the `switch` method. Any advice or example will be good.

Thanks all for helping me.

Comment: Anything not working with the given approach? It could be easier to just exchange the class name, instead of echo'ing the whole navigation within the `if` parts

Comment: Problem is that my navigation is called `<?php include 'navigation.php'; ?>` and can't change the class name on different pages because it's called. @NicoHaase

Comment: `$nav_class = 'white-color'; if (...) $nav_class = '...';` `<nav class="<?= $nav_class ?>">`…?

Comment: Why is that a problem? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
```

will return the file name that is currently in use. So if you are on localhost/index.php it will return index.php.

Furthermore you can make your code more effective by doing the following:

```
print "<nav class='";
if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == "index.php"){
    print "first-class";
}
else if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == "register.php"){
    print "second-class";
}
else{
    print "third-class";
}
print "'></nav>";
```

If we take into account the comment from deceze it would look like this.

```
if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == "index.php"){
    $navClass = "first-class";
}
else if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == "register.php"){
    $navClass = "second-class";
}
else{
    $navClass = "third-class";
}
print "<nav class='$navClass'></nav>";
```

Comment: `basename(__FILE__)` won't help if the whole navigation is part of `navigation.php`, as this will always return `navigation`

Comment: @NicoHaase Ahh alright, I understand my mistake, I will edit my answer

Comment: This not working for me, display only last class name @Dokik

Comment: @PHPStarter I just tried locally and it shows the correct file. Are you sure your files are called "index.php" and "register.php"?